# Reading and Writing text file when condition are meet

Tags: vbscript

I have a text file Sample.txt with that contains thousands of records.
See below. I have created vbscript that accept input box for the cut-off record. In this example I inputted 10005 as the cut-off record.
The script will then read all records after the cut-off record, in this case starting at 10006 down to  10010, then write to a new text file with the current date as file name like 20180920.txt

```
10000
10001
10002
10003
10004
10005
10006
10007
10008
10009
10010
```

Expected output:

```
10006
10007
10008
10009
10010
```

Sample script but not finished in writing the new file.

```
Dim Lastrecord
Dim IsFound, IsFound2
Dim CurrentDate
Const ForReading = 1
Set wShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
sFileSelected = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(sFileSelected)
Set objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile), ForReading)

CurrentDate = Replace(Date, "/", "")
Lastrecord = InputBox("Last Last Record:")
IsFound = 0
IsFound1 = 0

Do Until objFile1.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile1.ReadLine
    If Trim(strLine) = Trim(LastRecord) Then
        IsFound = 1
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

objFile1.Close

WScript.Echo strLine
WScript.Echo Trim(Lastrecord)
```

-------------------I have completed the script, see below credit to @Ansgar Wiechers.

```
Dim Lastrecord
Dim IsFound, IsFound2
Dim CurrentDate
Const ForReading = 1
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec=wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
sFileSelected = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
CurrentDate = Year(NOW) & Right("00" & Month(NOW), 2) & Right("00" & Day(NOW), 2) & Right("00" & Hour(NOW), 2) & Right("00" & Minute(NOW), 2) & Right("00" & Second(NOW), 2)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(sFileSelected)
Set objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile), ForReading)

    Lastrecord = InputBox("Last Last Record:")
    IsFound = False
    Set outFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) & "\" & CurrentDate & ".DAT", True)
    Do Until objFile1.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile1.ReadLine
        If IsFound Then outFile.WriteLine strLine
        If Trim(strLine) = Trim(LastRecord) Then IsFound = True
    Loop
        Wscript.Echo "New file created successfully at: " & objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) & "\" & CurrentDate & ".DAT"
    outFile.Close
objFile1.Close
```

Comment: Where is the script? Without it, its hard to tell how to fix your code

Comment: @PankajJaju , see above I append my initial script but writing to a new text file, I have not done it yet.

Comment: I am assuming there won't be any duplication in row counters (10005, 10005, etc)? Can you confirm?

Comment: @pankajJaju , there is possibilities but when it found the first hit no matter if it has duplicate it wil just get all record below and write it in different txt file.

Comment: Re-opened, b/c the alleged duplicate is about how to read/write files in general while the OP's question is about how to selectively write data from one file to another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of exiting from the loop write `strLine` to the output file after the cutoff line was found.

```
IsFound = False
Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\output.txt", 2)
Do Until objFile1.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile1.ReadLine
    If IsFound Then outFile.WriteLine strLine
    If Trim(strLine) = Trim(LastRecord) Then IsFound = True
Loop
outFile.Close
```

Comment: exactly, this is the solution.